# Android app that make use of camera2 not working on Android 5.01

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-camera2

I develop Android app that access phone camera using camera2, it works fine with AVD devices including AVD for LG G3 API level 22. On my personal LG G3 which runs Android 5.01 the part of the app which access the camera will not show the camera preview (resides within Textureview component).

Any idea why or how can I solve this ?

Comment: Did you find something on logcat? Missing permissions?

Comment: @manfcas it works fine with emulator so I guess the right permissions exist.